# Equivalent of PHP's dirname(__FILE__) in Apache Rewriting syntax?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Images are served from a folder outside Apache's public folder and Aliases are not wanted.

What is the keyword, if existing, to get the real path of the htaccess that contains the rewriting rules ?

```
# /website1.com/public/prod/ --> index.php & .htaccess
# /website1.com/assets/images/

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ REALPATH/../../assets/images/$1 [L] 
# REALPATH doesn't work of course

# not wanted :
# RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /website1.com/public/prod/assets/images/$1 [L]
```

Comment: By the way you can also use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: @ComFreek assuming PHP 5.3 or later

Comment: Could you make it relative to `${DOCUMENT_ROOT}`, or does it have to be dynamically specific to that .htaccess file?

Comment: It has to be specific to the .htaccess file

Comment: If the files are not accessible trough Apache, mod_rewrite can't help you.

Comment: Audun: I understand now. You should put it as a answer to my question

Comment: I'm entirely unsure what you want, but it sounds like an [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive might be in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access files outside of .htaccess directory, even using absolute path. Solution could be to make symbolic link in current folder that points to your images directory and then point your .htaccess rule to this file.

Your rule then should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /assets/images/$1 [L] #this is relative to your .htaccess file
```

Comment: I tried to use an Alias instead of the relative path but I couldn't make it work.
I'll try and surely set the symbolic link method.